# Dependency clashes between main project and aar module - Volley

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I'm using Volley library for networking in my current app.

Dependency :

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

I have provided a custom implementation for my Imageloader to override some headers needed for my server.

Code Below:

```
public class MyImageLoader extends ImageLoader {


    public MyImageLoader(RequestQueue queue, ImageCache imageCache) {
        super(queue, imageCache);
    }

    @Override
    protected Request<Bitmap> makeImageRequest(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight,
                                           ImageView.ScaleType scaleType, final String
                                                   cacheKey) {

         return new ImageRequest(requestUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            onGetImageSuccess(cacheKey, response);
        }
    }, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onGetImageError(cacheKey, error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //add my params
            return params;
        }
    };
}
```

}

I'm also using the Linkedin sdk aar for Linkedin integration.

Dependency snippet:

```
compile(name:'linkedin-sdk-debug', ext:'aar')

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

This aar also references its own version of volley which is a jar in the Linkedin SDK project.

Building my project is fine but when I run it I get a bunch of errors:

Errors below:

Error:(17, 9) error: constructor ImageRequest in class ImageRequest cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,Listener,int,int,Config,ErrorListener

found: String,Listener,int,int,ScaleType,Config,ErrorListener
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Error:(40, 16) error: constructor ImageRequest in class ImageRequest cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,Listener,int,int,Config,ErrorListener
found: String,>,int,int,ScaleType,Config,
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I suspect this could be due to a clash in different volley code versions.

Has anyone had this type of situation before?

Comment: where did you get this linkedin-sdk-debug.arr from ?

Comment: @djodjo from the linkedin zip on their site https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Comment: in this zip you have code not aar and also you have the volley in a separate folder

Comment: check my answer and i suggest you switch to com.android.volley:volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linkedin zip you have volley in a separate module so I  suggest you make you project that u have 3 modules:

1) your code

2) linkedin code

3)  - common volley code and compile project(':volley') in 1) and 2)
    OR
    - use compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' in 1) and 2)

note that if you want to stick to volley its better to use

> com.android.volley:volley

as

> com.mcxiaoke.volley:library

is not maintained anymore.

Comment: I just removed the volley jar and changed the dependencies to be the same one. Thanks